# how to get the length of a 2-d counter

Tags: python

build the counter:

```
class Counters:
    def __init__(self,cats)
        self.form = collections.defaultdict(collections.Counter)
```

I get the length of the first dimension:

```
len(counters.form.items())
```

How to get the length of the second dimension?

Comment: Ragged arrays don't have a second dimension per se, only nested structures.

Comment: shot in the dark here len(counters.form.keys())

Comment: Do you mean the maximum length? Or, the number of distinct values along that dimension?

Comment: @JanneKarila The number of distinct values along the second dimension? Actually, the number of distinct values along the second dimension is identical.

Comment: @dc5553 seems doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd want 2-d array in python, you should implement it that way:

```
x = 2
y = 3
nestedArray = [[0]*y for a in xrange(x)]
```

Then the array length would be x*y.

Or even better, **use classes**:

```
class NestedArray(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, defaultValue=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.array = [[defaultValue]*y for a in xrange(x)]

    def __len__(self):
        return self.x * self.y

    def __getitem__(self, key):
            return self.array[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
            self.array[key] = value
```

Comment: That's still not a 2D array though.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Why not?

Comment: You don't want `[]*n` which is actually `[]`

Comment: Because the size of each nested structure is independent of the rest.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams You can always change it with arrayObj[x] = [0]*n.

Comment: Exactly. A 2D array has two dimensions, not *x* different subsequence lengths.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't get it right. 2D Array IS x different subsequence lengths, isnt it?